# jquery/js closest().attr() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've only recently started learning JS, jQuery, HTML and CSS. Right now I'm trying to make my page, when a category class is clicked, animate and then redirecting to the link of the clicked item.

I've looked around a lot and got the `.closest(selector).attr('href')` thing or the parent thing. I tried both, and I just keep getting undefined for `linkto`

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="mainCon">
    <a href="programs.html">
      <li class="category">
        <img style="height: 150px;" src="programs.png" /><br /> 
        Programs
      </li>
    </a>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
$('.category').click(function() {
  $('.mainCon').animate({
    right: '100px',
    opacity: '0',
  }, 500, function() {
    var linkto = $(this).closest('a').attr('href');
    location.href= linkto;
  })
  return false;
});
```

Any idea why `linkto` always returns undefined? The linked html file(programs.html) is in the same directory as the page where I'm going to be coming from so I really don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Yours is invalid HTML. `li` can only be child of `ul`

Comment: Do like this `location.href = $(this).children('a').attr('href');` and correct html as suggested above

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yours is invalid HTML. `li` can only be child of `ul`,

Use

```
$('.category').click(function() {
    var self = $(this); //Cache this in a variable
    self.closest('.mainCon').animate({
        right: '100px',
        opacity: '0',
    }, 500, function() {
        var linkto = self.closest('a').attr('href');
        location.href= linkto;
    })
    return false;
});
```

OR

```
$('.category').click(function() {
    var self = $(this); 
    self.closest('.mainCon').animate({
        right: '100px',
        opacity: '0',
    }, 500, function() {
        var linkto = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        location.href= linkto;
    })
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the animate callback `this` is the `mainCon` element. [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is used to find an ancestor element, but in your case you need to find a descendant element so use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('.category').click(function() {
    $('.mainCon').animate({
        right: '100px',
        opacity: '0',
    }, 500, function() {
        var linkto = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        location.href= linkto;
    })
    return false;
});
```

Note: Your html is invalid, `li` can't be a child of `anchor` element

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use

```
var linkto = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
```

instead of

```
var linkto = $(this).closest('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

$('.mainCon'). (this) object and $('.category') (this) object are different, When you use $(this) under

```
$('.mainCon').animate()
```

that means you are in   `<div class="mainCon">` not `<li class="category">`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.category').click(function () {
                         // $(this) ==  $('.category')
                        $('.mainCon').animate({
                            right: '100px',
                            opacity: '0',
                        }, 500, function () {
                            // $(this) ==  $('.mainCon')
                            var linkto = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
                            /*  alert($(this).find('a').attr('href')); return false; */
                            location.href = linkto;
                        })
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="mainCon">
                    <a href="programs.html">
                        <li class="category">
                            <img style="height: 150px;" src="programs.png" /><br /> 
                            Programs
                        </li>
                    </a>
                </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .find() also.

`var link = $(this).find('a').attr('href')`